# Create new Profile Object in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I want to insert a new Record in Profile object, but when I try to insert with SOQL, it throws an error, CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: [object Object]: entity type cannot be inserted: Profile
,,

How do I resolve this problem. I have to add new records to Profile successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

[Profile object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm) does not support `create()` call.

Profiles are created for example with Metadata API (which is bit hard to access from APEX). You can easily create them if you're calling SF from external application (Eclipse IDE for example but also anything written in Java, .NET, PHP, Ruby...)

There are some code samples in the Metadata API guide: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm