# External Ids in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How do I create an External Id on objects like Profile (for which isCreatable is false). I have to create External Id on Profile for upsert operation, but I am not able to create it.

Is there any work around for this? Or Can we ask salesforce to allow us to create external ids.

Any links or references would be useful!!

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use this? I can understand needing external Ids for users, but for profiles I can't really come up with a reasonable use case.

Answer (score 2):

Follow up of [Create new Profile Object in salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545946/create-new-profile-object-in-salesforce)?

You can't create external Ids on the metadata components (Profiles, classes, visualforce pages, custom fields). Most of the time they're guarded by having `Name` or `DeveloperName` unique. (with addition of namespace but let's ignore managed packages for now)

Profile object doesn't support create but similarly it doesn't support upsert ;) Compare http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm and http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm

I don't understand what exactly are you trying to achieve?